# Batch Printing files to new folder as PDF's

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing

I have a folder of 2000+ PDF files that I need to print and resave as new PDF files in a separate folder using the original file name. Is there a way to do this in powershell or using a CMD?

I have tried to select multiple files in the folder to print at the same time by right clicking and selecting the print option. However this gets stuck at the window requesting a new file name and a destination folder which I am unable to provide as each file needs to have the original file name.

```
 // the directory to store the output.
 string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath  
 (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

 // initialize PrintDocument object
 PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument() {
     PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings() {
         // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
         PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

         // tell the object this document will print to file
         PrintToFile = true,

         // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
         PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + ".pdf"),
     }
    };

 doc.Print();
```

I would like to see the new PDF file saved as a new PDF in the destination directory folder with the same file name as the origin directory.

```
Origin Directory and File name:
C:\Users\ts\P***S***\Legal\i3**\NonRedacted  --> Origin File name "Random_Name.PDF"


Destination Directory and File name:
C:\Users\ts\P***S***\Legal\i3**\Redacted --> Destination File Name "Random_Name.PDF"
```

Comment: This doesn't look like PowerShell, more like C# or Java

Comment: You are correct it is not powershell. I am wondering if there is a way to do it in powershell. My apologies I should have made that more clear.